# I am getting error when i am sending mail in laravel

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, host, laravel-5.7

I am getting error when i am sending mail at gmail id,I am using laravel 5.7,
I am getting this errot

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\send()

and my controller code is :

```
public function postEmail(Request $r)
{
    $data=[
     'user_email'=>$r->user_email,
     'user_name'=>$r->user_name,
     'user_phone'=>$r->user_phone,
     'user_desc'=>$r->user_desc,
    ];


 Mail:send('mail.mail', $data, function($user_desc) use($data)
    {
       $message->from('sumitsaoni@gmail.com', 'Send by Sumit');
       $messge->to($data['sumit123@gmail.com']);
       $message->subject($data['user_desc']);
    });

    return redirect()->back()->with('message','successfully data insertd');
}
```

And My Route is

```
Route::resource('contact', 'ContactController');
Route::post('/postEmail', 'ContactController@postEmail');
```

My .env  file mail gmail: .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my_email (Using my email id)
MAIL_PASSWORD=password (using my email id password)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
use Mail;

Mail::send('mail', $data, function($user_desc) use($data)
{
    $message->from('sumitsaoni@gmail.com', 'Send by Sumit');
    $message->to($data['user_email']);
    $message->subject($data['user_desc']);
});
```

**Updated answer**

```
Mail::send('mail', $data, function($message) use($data)
    {
        $message->from('sumitsaoni@gmail.com', 'Send by Sumit');
        $message->to($data['user_email']);
        $message->subject($data['user_desc']);
    });
```

Comment: Change the code...i receive this message: Undefined variable: message

Comment: I put the same code which is given in your updated answer, but again i receive this error

Undefined variable: messge

Comment: i replace $messge to $message and the above problem solve...but now i am getting this error

Undefined index: sumit123@gmail.com

Comment: @Ramson: please replace $data['sumit123@gmail.com']   to $data['user_email'] also i have updated my answer please check

Comment: Now Getting this error:

View [mail.mail] not found.

I have a mail.blade.php file:

<section id="contact-us">
  <div class="contact">
<h1>Hello World {{$user_email}}</h1>
<p> {{!! $user_desc !!}}</p>
  </div>
</section>

Comment: @Ramson: Your `mail.blade.php` in **mail** folder?

Comment: @Ramson: Because mail.mail means 1st mail means folder name and 2nd mail means your your mail.blade.php

Comment: @Ramson: if your `mail.blade.php` file is alone means (i.e views/mail.blade.php) then please check my updated answer

Comment: i changed mail.mail to mail, because i do not have any mail folder in my view file, but now i receive this error:

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required "

Comment: @Ramson: this is different error so please create new question for that

Comment: @Saurabh...I run this command: php artisan config:cache
and i got the mail on my mail id...but i am getting my website header also

Comment: @Ramson: your header view include in your mail.blade.php so just remove and check

Comment: You solve my issue, Please let me know how i will accept your answer...

Comment: I make your answer accepted, i have 1 more issue...when i am entring any mail in my form and submitting the form, then i m getting mail at my mail id, but same time i receive another mail which show this message:

Address not found
Your message wasn't delivered to ddd@gmail.com because the address couldn't be found, or is unable to receive mail.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
Mail:send('mail.mail', $data, function($user_desc) use($data)
```

to

```
Mail::send('mail.mail', $data, function($user_desc) use($data)
```

Comment: Where did you get this code? I never found anything like that in Laravel documentation. I have always used Mailable class for sending mails.

Regarding your question, I am also wondering where did $message come from.

Comment: I updated with this code:

Mail::send('mail.mail', $data, function($message) use($data)
    {
        $message->from('sumitsaoni@gmail.com', 'Send by Sumit');
        $message->to($data['sumit123@gmail.com']);
        $message->subject($data['user_desc']);
    });

Above problem is solved, but now i am getting 
Undefined index: sumit123@gmail.com

Can u please help me how I can solve this ...

Answer (score 1):

try this one

`Mail:send` **to replace** `Mail::send`